# Creating dynamic buttons in Android like tiles

Tags: android

How to create a dynamic button view like this ?
Here +Add button is a static one. Other buttons should be dynamically created as in this picture. According to the retrieved data from a database this have t be created and with the add button it could add new buttons.

[image: Dynamic Button View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml file have a linear layout of orientation Vertical.

In the java class file declare it as

`ViewGroup lr = (ViewGroup)findViewVyId(R.id.dd)`

```
for(int i = 0; i < x1; i++)
{
     lr1 = new LinearLayout(this);
     lr1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HOIZONTAL);
     lr.addView(lr1);
     for(int j = 0; j < xx1; j++ )
     {
         if(i==0)
         {
        if(j == 0)
        {
          final View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nw, null);
          lr.addView(child);
        }
        else
        {
            lr2 = new LinearLayout(this);
            lr2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            for(int k = 0; k<2; k++)
            {
                final View b3 = new Button(this);
                lr2.addView(b3);
            }
            lr.addView(lr2);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        final View b2 = new Button(this);
        lr.addView(b2);
      }
      lr1.setId(main_cnt);
      main_cnt++;
          if(i == 2)
          {
        if(j == 2)
        {
            break;
        }
          }
     }
}
```

the first for loop decides how many layouts to be in vertical order and the second for loop decides how many button inside the linear layout in Horizontal order. The `main_cnt` is used to get an id for each button

The xml file of child is where i have place the Add(large button)